# Excel crashes when opening new file

Tags: windows-update, microsoft-excel-2013

HP notebook 8570p
Windows 7 64bit
MS Excel 2013

Excel crashes under these circumstances every time:
  (problem started after Windows Update Dec. 2014)
Excel is open, and a range in a workbook has been copied with CTL-C.
Open a new file with CTL-N.
Excel crashes immediately.

Coworker with same hardware but W7 32bit, Excel 2010, doesn't have this issue.
Coworker can do this:
Excel is open, and a range in a workbook has been copied with CTL-C.
Open a new file with CTL-N.
Paste in new workbook with CTL-V.
No problems - works perfectly.

Any suggestions? Seems to be associated with Dec. Windows Update.

Thanks

Comment: When you say, issue started after the Windows Updates then why don't you identify the recent updates installed in your machine and uninstall them to isolate the issue. When digging this issue for you, a skype patch update might causing this issue. Check whether you have anything related to skype or isolate the issue by uninstalling the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

I have severe Excel issues too since the Dec update. Both excel version - 2010 64 bit and 2013 64 bit - seem to have issues referencing embedded ActiveX objects.

For instance - I now get compile issues when the workbook opens and statements l like

```
set oActSheet = activesheet
oActSheet.CB_DropDown1.value = "Elephant"
```

does not recognise the `Object CB_Dropdown`

I believe it to be Windows related as Excel 2013 and Excel 2010 don't share anything at the app level.

Good old System Restore then disable Updates saved me here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix.  Close Excel, delete this file.  Excel will rebuild automatically and all should be good.

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd